# apple-touch-startup-image for iPhone 5 not loading if lower resolution is present

Tags: ios, iphone, iphone-web-app

I've added start-up-images for all iphone models to make sure everyone get the splash screen on their device. 
The problem is that If I keep the resolutions for iphone 4 and iPhone 3gs the start-up image for iphone 5 won't load.

This is my setup:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="images/splash-iphone6plus.png" media="(max-device-width:414px) and (max-device-height:736px)">
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="images/splash-iphone6.png" media="(max-device-width:375px)">
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="images/splash-iphone5.png" media="(max-device-width:548px)">
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="images/splash-iphone4.png" media="(max-device-width:480px)">
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="images/splash-iphone3gs.png" media="screen and (max-device-width:320px)">
```

If I don't comment out the lines for iphone 3 and 4 the start-up image won't show up on my iphone 5s.

I know your supposed to have the additional "and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)" for retina screens, but no difference plus I get a validation error if it's there.

Any clues?